# I can not find Rotation Numbers in EDIT mode

Tags: transforms

I can not find Rotation Numbers in EDIT mode.
I can see them in Object mode, but I do not want to rotate the entire Object, only certain Edges / faces.
Can you tell me where they are, or are they not in program at all ?

If not It would be extremely helpful to have rotation numbers ( editable, like all other location numbers are ), In EDIT mode.

Comment: ok I do see rotation numbers in "Transform", But, it still rotates ( In Edit Mode ) the entire object, which I do not want. I only want to Rotate Selected Edges / Faces.

Comment: I figured it out. I dint know I had to use transform Locks. All is well now.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the equivalent of the 
 [image]
for edit mode, there's little chance you have one, since it is simply difficult to define.

However, each faces has a Normal, which is a vector that points to the direction the face is facing. To obtain this value, take a look at the link below.

[Display values of a normal of a selected face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/display-values-of-a-normal-of-a-selected-face)

Comment: I can not see how it would be difficult to define numbers of a few edges / faces. Choose an edge, alter rotation with numbers. the program has an extraordinary amount of things you can adjust with numbers, in Edit mode, but cant show / alter rotation of an edge / face or two with numbers ? Not sure where to start with, what is wrong with that........But thanks for the info Allosteric

Comment: First take a look at this video https://youtu.be/HTG__j55g1g?list=PL3wFcRXImVPOQpi-wi7uriXBkykXVUntv to differenciate rotation from orientation. Now, as you pointed out, it is easy to define a rotation. However, what you are asking is (if I understand correctly) is the orientation of a geometry. To define a orientation from rotation, you will need a 'before rotated' state, which makes it difficult. In other words, there is no obvious answers to 'What is the default orientation of a geometry?"

Comment: example - flat ( start ) + 2 degrees ( end )

Comment: but more than 1 edge / face - a group selected - but rest of build stays still

Comment: Forgive me but I don't actually understand your proposal. Anyway, if you know a good idea to define an orientation, make a proposal in other sites such as right-click select or devtalk.blender.org since it is likely to be off topic for a QA site. (Of course, it won't be off topic if there's a widely shared consensus so remind me if that's the case)

Comment: All good I seem to have ( out of frustration ) solved it myself. Here's an image link of what I was trying to achieve - https://gyazo.com/4338f6cf821f21e06b4b7fe41d70339c

Answer (score 0):

How to find out the rotation value of a face:

- Select Face
- Align View > Align View to active > Top
- In Object mode add a cube
- In Add cube properties select Align to view (bottom left)
- Check the cubes rotation, that's the face rotation

However I think it is totally fine that it isn't easily accessible, I've been using blender for about a year and only needed this a couple of times.