# Get or display normal vector / coordinates of selected vertex?

Tags: vertices, faces, normals, coordinates, vector

*I have a .stl file and want to get the normal vector of a selected vertex or face in relation to the origin.*

Blender only shows the coordinates of that vertex/face. My blender skills are very limited so after a few hours of trying, I wasn't able to get information about the normal vector displayed.

[image]

**Q:** Is there a way to get the normal vector of the vertex or a face?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately i dont know a way to display the normal vector in the viewport.
Here are two options to get the normal  vector. I'd say it depends on what you want to do with the normal vector after getting it...

Option 1 Python:

```
import bpy

mesh = bpy.context.object.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

selected_verts = [v for v in mesh.vertices if v.select]

for v in selected_verts:    
    print(f"Vertex Normal: {v.normal}")
```

Option 2 Add-On Animation Nodes:

[image]
I filtered all the normals with a vertex group I did manually.

additional: here are some answers for modifiing the ui to display normal-information:
[Display values of a normal of a selected face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/display-values-of-a-normal-of-a-selected-face)

Comment: Hi and thankyou for your two options to solve my problem. I tried option 2, had to figure out all about the Animation Node Add-On. By now I dont get any values in the viewers. I made a few vertex groups, do I have to select the vertex group?

Comment: Option 1: is working perfectly!